# Hiding Window MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two Window's. I want to open one and hide/close the current one.

```
GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"                   
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  Visibility="{Binding WindowVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

ViewModel:

```
  var taskViewModel = new EmployeViewModel(Convert.ToInt32(userId)); 
  Window2 X = new Window2(taskViewModel);
  WindowVisible = false;
  X.Show();

   private bool _windowVisible;
   public bool WindowVisible
    {
        get { return _windowVisible; }
        set
        {
            _windowVisible = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("WindowVisible");
        }

    }
```

The second window is opening but nothing is happening to the first.

Comment: More detail pls. where you set WindowVisible = false; ? , in a method or constructor? BooleanToVisibilityConverter converts to Collapsed or Hidden when false?

Comment: @ThierryV I tried in the constructor, It didn't do anything, so the code above is running as a command for a button and It's for "Hidden".

Comment: @ThierryV Sorry, It's collapsed. I just checked again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XAML to this

```
GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"                   
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
<Window.Resources>
     <!--YOUR CONVERTER -->
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="WindowVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
</Window.Visibility>
```

If still not working, put a breakpoint on `WindowVisible` getter and watch if the converter is trying to get it.

I have just tried this and it worked so let me know if it didn't for you

Comment: How come it did work for you? It's still not for me. I did set the breakpoint but I honestly don't know what you mean by "watch if the converter is trying to get it".

Comment: @Hackawar I did exactly what you posted. 2 Windows, 1 opens the other and becomes "Collapsed". jsut the way you did and it worked. Did u try my code ? When you put a converter to a property, the converter is called with the property and returns the converted value so if you put a breakpoint in your WindowVisible get you iwll see if its called. What's more, when you put a property bound in your view, the way it gets the value is calling the getter of the property so WindowVisible getter should be called

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload it to GitHub please? This is so weird. I tried to create a separate project and It's still not working. If I bind that property to a button or something, It works, but for the window, still nothing happens.

Comment: Even with the code I posted in my answer ? I’ll try to upload it to GitHub

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to override the window's content.

```
ContentOverride.OverRideContent<WindowtobeHide>(userControl);

public static class ContentOverride
{
    public static void OverRideContent<T>(UserControl objMain)
    {
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {                    
                window.Content = objMain;
                window.Activate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use

```
 window.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

to hide instead of replacing the content like what I am doing

Answer (score -1):

You can write an `InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter`.